# Accessing an implemented abstract property in the constructor causes CA2214

Tags: c#, constructor

I am using a code analysis, but I have a problem with Overridable methods in constructors

```
public partial class ControlAdmin : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly DatabaseManagement _dm = new DatabaseManagement();
    // more stuff.....
}
```

Comment: _"Overddidable nethodes"_ https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ (_...Have you checked the spelling and grammar to the best of your ability?_)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You've talked about overridable methods, but you haven't demonstrated the problem in your code, or specified the exact error message - that makes it really hard to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning states, you *shouldn't* call a virtual Member of your class from the constructor, because your members might not be fully initialized, when the Method is called. Consider the following example.

```
class Foo
{
    protected Bar _someBar;

    public Foo()
    {
        _someBar = new Bar();
       InitBar();
    }

    protected void InitBar()
    {
        _someBar.SomeImportentMethod();
    }
}

class Baz : Bar
{

    private int _id:

    public Baz(int id) : base()
    {
         _id = id;
    }

    protected override InitBaz()
    {
       base.InitBaz();
        _someBaz.Id = _id;
    }
}
```

In this code you try to access a member variable of the derived class (`_id`). But at the time `InitBaz` is executed, that variable hasn't been asigned, so you'd initialize `_someBaz` with a wrong value. CA2214 warns you about that danger.